# Reading in an array of 12 numbers with spaces in between each number - C programming

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am a new C programming student and am having trouble with a code I am currently working on. I need to ask the user for a 12 number barcode with spaces in between each value. Also, I will need to refer to each individual value in the array later on in the code. For example, if my array is `x[12]`, I need to use `x[1]`, `x[2]`, and all other values to calculate the odd sum, even sum, etc. Below is my first function to read in the bar code using a for loop. Any assistance for the script of this function would help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

int fill_array() {
    int x[ARRAY_SIZE], i;
    printf("Enter a bar code to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");

    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        scanf("% d", &x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass array to read as the argument and store what is read there.

Also note that `% d` is a invalid format specifier for `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

/* return 1 if suceeded, 0 if failed */
int fill_array(int* x) {
    int i;
    printf("Enter a bar code to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");

    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        if(scanf("%d", &x[i]) != 1) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i;
    if(fill_array(bar_code)) {
        for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) printf("%d,", bar_code[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    } else {
        puts("failed to read");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternately, you can allocate an array in the function and return its address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

/* return address of array if succeeded, NULL if failed */
int* fill_array(void) {
    int *x, i;
    x = malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
    if (x == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter a bar code to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");

    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        if(scanf("%d", &x[i]) != 1) {
            free(x);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    int *bar_code;
    int i;
    if((bar_code = fill_array()) != NULL) {
        for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) printf("%d,", bar_code[i]);
        putchar('\n');
        free(bar_code);
    } else {
        puts("failed to read");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO it would be good to pass the size (`size_t`) of the array as parameter, too.